# Can I switch the testing framework of a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

When I started my Rails app, I chose RSpec as my testing framework, because of all the hype. Now, I'm trying to write more tests, and I find that I don't like to write tests this way. I'd like to switch back to the default testing framework.

How could I do this switch? I'm using Rails 3.0.5

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't know if you are aware, but if you use assertions instead of rspec-expectations (`obj.should matcher`), which you can already do without any additional configuration, then the only difference is this:

```
# w/ Test::Unit
class FooControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "something or other" do
    ...
  end
end

# w/ RSpec
describe FooController do
  it "does something or other" do
     ...
  end
end
```

Everything else that you can write using Test::Unit in Rails, you can write using RSpec exactly the same way.

Then you get all the non-syntax-related benefits of RSpec like readable output, a robust command line tool with its own -help output, etc.

I realize that doesn't answer the question you're asking, but I hope it helps you in your decision process.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an either/or situation. You can have RSpec and Test::Unit tests in the same Rails application, so just begin writing Test::Unit tests. No need to switch, just do new development with Test::Unit.

Depending on how you run your tests, your CI setup, and how you have modified your app this may be more or less changes, but in practice these are straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

in config/application.rb

```
module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application

    generate.test_framework :test_unit, :fixture => false # :rspec <- before

    ...
```

New models/controllers generate the basic test/* files